# Rails self join with condition only apply to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Take http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins for example,

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

If I would like to apply to a condition, saying, only **Employee** with **is_manager**(assuming Employee has such boolean field) is **true**, is manager and could display **subordinates**

If I simply change the above to the below

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, -> {where is_manager: true}, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

It will not work since the condition `where is_manager: true` will apply to `subordinates` as well.

```
FROM `employees` WHERE `employees`.`is_manager` = 1 AND (employees.manager_id = 1)
```

But I want to only apply to manager, rather than subordinates.

Something like

```
Employee.where(manager_id: employee.where(is_manager: true))
```

So that, if I call

```
employee = Employee.find 1 
employee.subordinates
```

First, it will check whether employee is manager, if yes, return subordinates; otherwise, return empty array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a class method[1], `as_manager`. Something like:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"

  class << self

    def as_manager
      where(is_manager: true)
    end

  end
end
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
Employee.as_manager.subordinates
```

Or, given your 'business requirement' (very strange that the business would be have requirements for this level of implementation detail), how about you just preempt the `subordinates` method provided by the `has_many` directive?

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "manager_id"
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"

  def subordinates
    is_manager ? where(manager_id: id) : []
  end

end
```

That way, you can keep all the other methods provided by `has_many`, but get the behavior you want for `subordinates`.

[1] [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to state:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Let it be fully understood by all parties that the term *class method* is used above in its colloquial sense.

Comment: Sorry, this is biz requirement. I cannot change that. It has to be `employee.subordinates`. No negotiation.

Comment: Ah, well, you didn't say that. It's a very strange *business* requirement.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It is biz requirement since we offer json api externally. It is one of relationships.